# Finding LaTex output files

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, texstudio, auxiliary-files

I'm using TeXstudio 2.6.2 with MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4535 on Windows7.

I configured TeXstudio to store all output files in a separate directory.

It now looks like this:

```
-src
    |_Report.tex
    |_*.tex (all chapters)
    |_Report.bib
-build
    |_Report.pdf
    |_Report.log
    |_Report.bbl
    |_*.aux
```

which is my desired structure.

My problems are

1. There are many messages like "citation 'X' on page Y undefined. There's the error message "no file Report.bbl"
2. the inbuilt pdf-viewer doesn't open (find?) Report.pdf

My configuration looks looks this:
[image]

How do I have to configure TeXstudio properly  in order to solve these issues?

Comment: Did you run `bibtex`?

Comment: @Sigur yes I did

Comment: 99 times out of a 100 when someone configures tex to write the output somewhere non standard people get error messages with one or other of the auxiliary programs not finding stuff. It is _so_ much easier just not to do that, and to let Tex write stuff where everything expects things to be written....

Comment: You've tagged the question with `biblatex`, do you use that package? `biblatex` package uses `biber` as default bibliography backend, so running `bibtex` wont help unless you've specified `backend=bibtex`.

Comment: It is quite possible that miktex doesn't write some of your files due to security restrictions as you are trying to write to a folder which is not a subfolder of your current directory. Beside this I agree with David.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Answer (score 1):

Biber does not know the option `--include-directory`.

If you use the TeX switch `-output-directory` or some kind of build folder option of your editor/IDE, you will need to tell Biber so using either of the
`--input-directory` or `--output-directory` options.

Biber's help explains the two thus

> ```
> --input-directory [directory]
>     .bcf and data files will be looked for first in the directory. See
>     the biber PDF documentation for the other possibilities and how this
>     interacts with the "--output_directory" option.
>
> --output-directory [directory]
>     Output files (including log files) are output to directory instead
>     of the current directory. Input files are also looked for in
>     directory before current directory (but after "--input_directory" if
>     that is specified).
> ```

In your case you would need

```
biber --output-directory=../build %
```

Which works perfectly together with MikTeX's `--output-directory` and `--aux-directory`.