# Changing the aux folder for makeglossaries

Tags: auxiliary-files, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with Latex Workshop and I am changing the directory for the auxiliary and output files to a directory called .aux (I want it to stay hidden if possible).

My reciepe looks like this:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "build",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "biber",
                "pdflatex",
                "makeglossaries",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

I managed to add the output folder to pdflatex and biber parts but makeglossaries gives this error:

```
Unable to chdir to ' .aux' No such file or directory
makeglossaries version 4.45 (2020-01-18)
```

I tried this:

```
        {
            "name": "makeglossaries",
            "command": "makeglossaries",
            "args": [
                "-d .aux",
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152843/finding-latex-output-files#comment348887_152843

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution

```
    {
        "name": "makeglossaries",
        "command": "makeglossaries",
        "args": [
            "-d.aux",
            "%DOCFILE%"
        ]
    },
```

No space between flag and new directory.